# FlutterReactiveBle not connecting to BLE device while rfnconnect succeeds

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the flutter_reactive_ble package to connect to a BLE device in my Flutter project. My goal is to find devices with a specific name (in this case, devices with a name containing "xxxx"), and then connect to that device.

The issue is that, even though I see the device during scanning and try to connect, the connection doesn't seem to happen, and my connection stream doesn't receive any updates. However, when I use the rfnconnect app on my device, I can connect with no issues.

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
_discoveredStream = ble.scanForDevices(
  // ... other options ...
).listen((scannedDevice) {
  if (scannedDevice.name != null && scannedDevice.name!.contains('xxxx')) {
    // ... logic to add device to a list ...
    _connectGatt(device.id); // Try to connect to the device
  }
});

void _connectGatt(String deviceId) {
  _connectionStream = ble.connectToAdvertisingDevice(
    id: deviceId,
    // ... other options ...
  ).listen((connectionUpdate) {
    print('Connection Update Received: $connectionUpdate');
    // ... handle connection states ...
  }, onError: (err) {
    print("Error during connection: $err");
  });
}
```

However, the _connectGatt method doesn't seem to work as expected. I'm not getting any updates from the connection, and I can't figure out why.

Does anyone have experience with flutter_reactive_ble and knows why I might be having this issue? Is there something obvious I'm missing? Thanks for any help.